# How to know fps of game running on Mesa 3D on Windows 10

Tags: opengl, windows, frame-rate, mesa

I am running some old OpenGL 3D application. I don´t have source code from the application but I assume it was implemented with OpenGL 2.0 or 2.1. I am running it on Windows 10 on Intel UHD graphics 630 and doing some comparison using standard Windows/Intel OpenGL drivers vs. Mesa3D and need to know FPS. When application is launched using standard Win/Intel drivers I can use Fraps tool or Microsoft Game Bar (Win + G buttons) to see FPS. But when I launch the application using Mesa3D (using libglapi.dll, opengl32.dll, dxil.dll, libgallium_wgl.dll) no application is possible to display the FPS. Obviously most of the tools acquire FPS from standard drivers and using Mesa3D those drivers are not used so not possible to display FPS. Is there some way or some tool to get know FPS on Mesa on Windows? Something like Gallium HUD for Linux?

Comment: This might be a better question for [Software Recommendations](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/search?q=fps).

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is not about developing a game of your own.

Comment: But it is still about development. I am working on workarounds to run the 3D app on new HW and Win10 (previously for Win XP and OpenGL 2). Now there are some rendering issues so I solved that using Mesa3D but need to know fps with Mesa as the rendering is lagging.